# Why is my flow not returning the same results live as when I debug it?

Tags: visual-workflow, contact, debugging, screen-flow, contracts

I need your help to point me towards what might be wrong with my flow...

I have created a screen flow that fetches a contract record's company account and all the contacts in that company who are listed as tutors. Then it should allow me to pick an available tutor for the current contract record.

My problem is when I debug it, it works fine, but in live it gets the wrong contacts and actually always returns the same two contacts from two different companies, regardless of the actual contract record.

[image]

Here's my flow:
[image]

And my debug:
[image]

Thank you for any help you might bring!

Comment: when run live, are you the same user as when debugged in setup?  Are you using the same ContractId? Is the version of the flow you are debugging activated? Is the screen flow action associated to the same flow you debugged? You can also turn on debugging for the running user and verify against the debug above.

Comment: Yes, I am the same user, and on the example above, I'm using the same ContractId. The version of the flow is activated, the screen flow action is associated to the same flow I tried debugging. 

**However, I have noticed that if I run that flow live with any other ContractId, I'm still getting the same results (the table with Romane ABILY and Marc LO) even though the contract records are linked to other companies. What's more Romane ABILY and Marc LO are from two distinct companies.**

Answer (score 2):

I hope this might help someone else in the same situation:
In the lightning App Builder where I manage my screen flow, I had not checked "Pass record ID into this variable".

[image]

Comment: Brilliant -- glad you figured this out and provided an answer for the community